# How to find unique representation of $\vec{u}$ as a linear combination of $\vec{b}_1$ and $\vec{b}_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the unique representation of $\vec{u} = [a, b]$ as a linear combination of $\vec{b}_1 = [2, -1]$ and $\vec{b}_2 = [-1, 1]$.

---

I feel like I might need some scalars or something else to complete this task.

Comment: Did you learn about the Gaussian algorithm?

Comment: Yes. Am I supposed to create an augmented matrix from the information I have been given and use reduced row echelon form?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that any linear combination of $\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2$, using the constants $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ can be written as
$$
x \vec{b}_1 + y\vec{b}_2
 = x \begin{pmatrix}  2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
 + y \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\  1 \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} 2  & -1 \\ -1 &  1\end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
$$
and so you are looking to solve
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2  & -1 \\ -1 &  1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This simply asks you to find reals $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which solve the following equation:

$$u=\alpha \cdot b_1 + \beta \cdot b_2$$

We can expand this into a system of real linear equations:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
a=\alpha \cdot 2 + \beta \cdot (-1)\\
b=\alpha \cdot (-1) + \beta \cdot 1\\
\end{array}\right.$$

This is a system of two equations in two unkowns ($\alpha, \beta$). You can use your favorite method to solve it. For insttance, if we add them up we find that

$$a+b=\alpha$$

And hence substituting back we get that $\beta = a+2b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: note by direct inspection that

$$
\begin{align}
[1,0] & = [2,-1] + [-1,1] = b_1+b_2 \\
[0,1] & = \frac{1}{3}\big([2,1] + 2 \cdot [-1,1]\big) = \frac{1}{3}(b_1+2b_2)
\end{align}
$$

Then $u = [a,b] = a \cdot [1,0] + b \cdot [0,1] = \cdots$